# Where do I find the correct version number for a GitHub release using JitPack?

Tags: maven, dependencies, version, jitpack

I am deploying a library through GitHub and I am using JitPack to use the library in a Maven dependency.

In GitHub, I entered "2.0" as the tag.

When I lookup my library on jitpack.io, In indeed see version 2.0 listed. According to JitPack, I need to add the following dependency to use my library:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.mwbouwkamp</groupId>
    <artifactId>numbers-lib</artifactId>
    <version>Tag</version>
</dependency>
```

However, when I add this to my pom-file, "Tag" is in red and it says that the dependency is not found. Same happens when I use "2.0" as a version (instead of "Tag").

Anyone knows where I go wrong?

FYI: I did try "Update Maven Indices" and I also tried a re-import.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, still don't know why the original solution did not work (so if anyone cares to explain, please do so), but I found the solution.

If, in jitpack.io you go to your library, you can also open a tab called [Builds]. This contains other version numbers! If I use these, it does work.